# How to return only the latest entries from a list using QUERY function?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I would like to return a filtered list of products to only show the latest entry for each product in the list (meaning pick the row with the MAX date for each product).

I have setup a QUERY function using the MAX(date) in the select clause, but the problem is that it is showing all values (i.e. not showing the latest entries only).

The query I have setup is:

```
=QUERY('SKU list'!A:C,"select max(A),B,C where A is not null group by B,C")
```

[A sheet with sample data and query is here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fTDX3jMfs4KSUUpSMsvq5ucPyhbYmKHeqCbx0ijeB4Y/edit#gid=859995557)

The actual result is that the query is returning old and new rows, I expect the query to only return the latest rows for each product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
={"max Date entered", "SKU", "MSRP"; 
 QUERY(ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(UNIQUE(B4:B), QUERY({A4:C},
 "select Col2,Col1,Col3 
  where Col1 is not null 
  order by Col2, Col1 desc", 0), {2,1,3}, 0))),
 "where Col1 is not null 
  order by Col2 
  format Col1 'dd/mm/yyyy'")}
```

[image: 0]

Comment: This is great. I noticed though that it doesn't sort by numerical order, as it has 10 and 11 after 1 because they start with the number 1, instead of going sku 1, sku 2, sku 3, sku 4, and so on. Is it possible to sort it like this? @player0

Comment: @user14915635 sure, why not. see the pink cell: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10Ddljxz1WQZXoS5EFXp7mXIaAXGE9J035tVUrY7uFQY/edit#gid=1812085657